# Prevent users from creating new sheets in a shared google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have created a spreadsheet with all sheets protected from editing except for a single cell, where the user is supposed to enter a search value, which filters the sheet. I shared the spreadsheet with enabled editing to allow for that, but that also enables users to create new sheets, which I'd like to prevent.

Perhaps I'm using not the most optimal way of achieving what I want, so suggestions are welcome. I saw people advising to use forms in similar use cases, but I don't see how to apply their survey capabilities to my needs.

EDIt: here is the shared spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C4mrBWJxPLrFQ4bp82UA2ICOr1e6ER47wF7YuElyoZg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a script to delete every newly created (not by the owner) sheet. Here is an example of such a script :

```js
// Deletes any tab named "SheetN" where N is a number 
function DeleteNewSheets() {
  var newSheetName = /^Sheet[\d]+$/
  var ssdoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ssdoc.getSheets();
  
  // is the change made by the owner ?
  if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() == ssdoc.getOwner().getEmail()) {
    return;
  }
  // if not the owner, delete all unauthorised sheets
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (newSheetName.test(sheets[i].getName())) {
      ssdoc.deleteSheet(sheets[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Then set a trigger that runs this function `DeleteNewSheets` when a **change** (like sheet creation) happens.

*Note : If english is not the document language you should change the regular expression `/^Sheet[\d]+$/`, for example for french it should be `/^Feuille [\d]+$/`.*

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have a query here, is there a way to stop saving any changes made by other people except owner?

Comment: @The_Learner you could set the sharing permissions to view only

Comment: If the name from sheet is changed, the script no works

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your existing spreadsheet, Seedmanc, Google's "Filter views" option under the "Data" menu of your Sheet could be helpful, because it lets owners/editors create and save filters that are accessible to view-only users too.

What's more, view-only users can create filter views unique to them. Once they enter a filter range, menu arrows appear...

[image]

...allowing them to filter either by condition (including custom formulas!) or by values. So, depending on how elaborate your filter is and how spreadsheet-savvy your users are, filter views can provide a more flexible filter while still protecting your sheets.

(Read more about Google Sheets [filter views here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?hl=en).)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here is the shared spreadsheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C4mrBWJxPLrFQ4bp82UA2ICOr1e6ER47wF7YuElyoZg/edit?usp=sharing  I did try using filters before, but a simple filter that searches for a word in a second column fails to show category names (green) in the first column of my sheet, because the corresponding cell of 2nd column is empty. Therefore I had to use custom Query call. Plus I would like to keep it user-friendly so the user will only have to enter a search value into a cell without doing filter views.

Comment: If you create a new column for magazine categories (e.g. Col A = Date, Col B = Category, Col C = Names), then filtering would likely be much simpler for your users. It could also increase the specificity of a filter. For example, users could filter by values in Col B to select "hm3 Special:" _and_ filter by condition in Col C where text contains "mizuki".

Comment: While this solves the user's problem, others may not be able to revoke Edit access. Is there a way to prevent adding sheets for those cases?